# Information disappears when I rotate the phone

Tags: android, android-orientation

I wrote a programm,you must fill edittext and save it in the list view but when I rotate my phone the whole information is lost.What can I do not to lose my information?

Comment: For starters, you'll want to familiarize yourself with the android developer documentation on the Activity lifecycle as found here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout is reloaded on each screen rotation.

You can bypass this by doing the following:

Add this in the **AndroidManifest.xml** to the activity that should not be reloaded:

```
<activity
    ...
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    ...
</activity>
```

In the source code of the activity add the following method:

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
       super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Just leave the method blank, and when the screen rotates nothing will be reloaded.

Comment: why should you override a method and then just calling the super method with the same argument?

Comment: It just does the trick not to lose the current layout that is in use.

Comment: Possibly yes, but does it really make a difference?

Comment: Edited my answer. Just copy&pasted it from one of my current projects. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: ok, now it makes a difference, i meant to just not to override that method